# Subset sum of which the sum is a huge float number

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

I'm trying to solve the subset sum problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem, or https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/class/02713-s13/lectures/lec15-subsetsum.pdf).

However, I have some special conditions. The set S consist of **one thousand to ten thousand huge float numbers**(about 10^8), the target sum W is also a **very huge**(about 10^9) float.

Now I want to obtain a subset, of which elements sum is as close as to W. I want to solve it with dynamic programming. But the size of table that stores medium results is too big to be acceptable. At the same time, the inner loop(for i = 1 to W) is also not acceptable.

Is there any efficient algorithm to solve this kind of subset problem?

Comment: @MitchWheat thanks for pointing it out and I've corrected it :-)

Comment: The size of the floats doesn't matter (you can just divide through by 10^8 to get smallish floats), but your problem, as stated, has no properties that differentiates it from the general subset sum which is NP-hard.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that the large numbers do very little in this case as the limit of double precision is around 10^310 (give or take a few orders of magnitude). The much larger issue is that there are 2^n subsets, so any n greater than around 30 is far too big. Towards the end of the Wikipedia page you linked, there is a polynomial time approximation, which is likely worth looking more into.

Also, the dp solution requires a fixed amount of values for the numbers to be. Considering you're looking at float precision, this is not feasible.